# Multiplication of nilpotent zero-trace matrix with another full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it true that the trace of $XHYH$ equals zero, where $tr(X) = tr(Y) = 0,\, X^2 = Y^2 = [0]_{n \times n}$ and $H$ is of rank $n$? (All of them are $n \times n$ square matrix and defined over some arbitrary field of char $\neq 2$)

Comment: Consider $X = Y = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1   \end{pmatrix}$ and  $H= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1   \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks, @user3257842.

Comment: I did some changes to the question, do you have a counterexample for this one, too? @user3257842

Comment: $X= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0   \end{pmatrix}$
$Y= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 1 & 0   \end{pmatrix}$
$H= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1   \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you so much, @user3257842.